# Direct way to add prop variable to React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So if I am creating a child component with varying props as shown in code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Jumbotron,
  Button,
  Col,
  Row } from 'reactstrap';
import './jumbo.css';
import './index.css';


export const CustHero = () =>
  <Jumbotron className="customerView">
    <h1 className="display-3">{this.props.group} Customer Connection</h1>
    <p className="lead">{this.props.leadtext}</p>
  </Jumbotron>

  export const GenHero = () =>
  <Jumbotron className="generalView">
    <h1 className="display-3">{this.props.group} Customer Connection</h1>
    <p className="lead">{this.props.leadtext}</p>
  </Jumbotron>
```

And in one parent, I have:

```
<CustHero group="Immerse" leadtext="Help the Immerse team organize an onsite customer visit for you and your team" />
```

And then in another I have:

While in another I have:

```
<GenHero group="Immerse" leadtext="Help the Immerse team organize an onsite customer visit for you and your team" />
```

But my props get messed up so am assuming that since I am doing these as multiple `const` in one component then importing, I have to define the props elsewhere?

If I do it as one a piece, meaning one file for GenHero then another for CustHero, there is no issue with the `const`. What am I doing wrong here? Yes, I am looking at docs on this. I do it this way as I cannot have multiple `export default` per component. Am I missing how to `map` with this even though since I am not binding a function, but simple adding a styling element with some text based on the component the child is used in?

**Addition:**

And I get this after the first answer still. Still something with `props`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const CustHero = (props) =>
  <Jumbotron className="customerView">
    <h1 className="display-3">{props.group && props.group} Customer Connection</h1>
    <p className="lead">{props.leadtext && props.leadtext}</p>
  </Jumbotron>

  export const GenHero = (props) =>
  <Jumbotron className="generalView">
    <h1 className="display-3">{props.group && props.group} Customer Connection</h1>
    <p className="lead">{props.leadtext && props.leadtext}</p>
  </Jumbotron>
```

Comment: what does `{props.group && props.group}` do and why duplicate?

Comment: if props.group is defined render it

Comment: you dont need prop-types to pass a prop down to a component

Comment: `<CustHero group="Immerse" leadtext={"Help the Immerse team organize an onsite customer visit for you and your team"} />` I think the text should be in brackets

Comment: It is all text and renders correctly now per your earlier answer.